# Comparator for boost::any underlying type

Tags: c++, boost-any

I have a struct that is used for Tokenizing a byte stream (`std::vector<uint8_t>`). The stream can contain bytes, words, dwords, null-terminated strings and raw data.

```
struct Token {
    enum TokenClass {
        BYTE, WORD, INT, SZCHAR, DATA
    };

    TokenClass type;
    boost::any value;

    Token( TokenClass c, uint8_t b ) : type(c), value(b) { }
    Token( TokenClass c, uint16_t w ) : type(c), value(w) { }
    ... etc.
};
```

It seems to work up to the point where I try to check the value in a unit test.

ie:

```
// ts is of type std::vector<Token>
CHECK_EQUAL(Token::WORD, ts[0].type); // fine
CHECK_EQUAL(257, ts[0].value); // error!
```

gives an error of

> error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘const boost::any’
>   and ‘const int’)
>          if (!(expected == actual))

So I added a comparator to the class, just for the int:

```
bool operator==(const int rhs) const
{
    return boost::any_cast<int>(value) == rhs;
}
```

But that did nothing to alleviate the issue.

How do I compare the underlying type with values since once I start validation code then I will need to be able to compare values.

Also would `boost::variant` be better suited to what I need to do?  In my quick read through of both it appeared that `any` was more suited to my task.

Comment: What if `value` is not an `int`? What if it's a `some_random_object`? What should the comparison do?

Comment: You should be able to do `CHECK_EQUAL(257, boost::any_cast<uint16_t>(ts[0].value));` in this particular case, for example. But you have to know exactly the type of the object contained in a `boost::any` to extract it.  That is, `boost::any a{static_cast<uint16_t>(0)}; boost::any_cast<uint32_t>(a);` will be a runtime error. This is why `boost::any_cast<int>(value)` doesn't work -- you're not storing an `int`, you're storing a `uint16_t`.

Comment: The data coming in is a set of bytes that can represent any one of the 4 types.  DATA, the 5th type, is just the base data being passed on (for further tokenising down the stream).  Eventually the 4 types will need comparators but I was writing the unit tests and chose to do WORD first, hence the need to compare the tokenised value with that should be in there (01, 01) == (257).

Comment: While ```boost::any_cast<uint16_t>(...)``` may work in a unit test, it will get very tiresome very quickly in practical code. Hence my requirement for a comparator.  Would switching to ```boost::variant``` be a better option?

Comment: It might help to remember that, internally, `boost::any` allocates a new object to store the value on the heap (`new uint16_t`) and stores the pointer in a `void *`. You can't `any_cast` directly to `int` for the same reason that reinterpreting a `uint16_t *` as `int *` would give very wrong results (and also undefined behavior).

Comment: I would of thought the ```uint16_t``` would be promoted to an int for the test.

Comment: Bear in mind that `any_cast` is casting a pointer, *not* a value, under the hood. You can't even extract a value from a `void *` without knowing *exactly* the type of object it points to. *Then* you can promote to other numeric types, but not before.

Comment: So would switching to ```boost::variant``` be a better choice?

Comment: Also, to address *"it will get very tiresome very quickly in practical code."* Another thing to keep in mind is that, while it might be tiresome, it's also validating that the type of the value stored in the `boost::any` is what you expect -- so it's not wasted code. It's verifying something important.

Comment: I will take a look at ```boost::variant```.